# How to retrieve value from name attribute using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to know what is the proper jQuery command that will allow me to extract "1" below in the code.

```
<td class="a" data-title="b">
<span name="number">1</span>
</td>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Docs : http://api.jquery.com/text/ - and your question is unclear : your title and your actual question asks two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('[name="number"]').html()` would also work in this case, and depending on whether you want html or text contents, you can try either

Answer (score 1):

You can target your element using the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and then get the value using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$('[name="number"]').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the [attr] in jQuery to do this. Example:

```
$('yorspan').attr("name")
```

Another way would be this:

```
$('[name]').attr('name')
```

That grabs all tags with the name attribute.

Comment: My apologies, I read the code wrong. The prior post is correct for you.